# How can one print out the fully qualified type of a Chapel variable?

Tags: chapel

To print out the type of a variable, I normally just use

```
writeln(x.type : string);
```

However, this doesn't print out the fully qualified name (which is useful when one is debugging shadowed variables). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: To clarify: By "fully qualified" do you mean "including the name of the module in which it was defined?"

Comment: @brad -- yes. Just to give this more context, this was prompted by https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/11907 which was caused by one variable shadowing another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think Chapel has any support for that today.  Off the top of my head, it seems like it would be reasonable to request a routine in the Reflection module that would take a symbol as an argument and give back its fully qualified module path as a string.  If that would be of interest, I'd suggest opening a feature request on Chapel's [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues).

Comment: done. For future reference, this can be tracked here : https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/11925